# How to write a (GNU)makefile with output different than the target?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have script that takes in a filename and generates multiple files with same name but different extension. I want to write a `makefile` that depends on files generated with different extension but only specify the filename. I have a dummy example to explain it below.

```
test_output:test_input
    genereate.py -i $^ -o $@
```

The above `makefile` dependency generates multiple files with same filename but different extension, but won't generate the actual target. For example, it generates

```
test_output.a test_output.b test_output.c
```

The way its written above is not the efficient way as there no actual target, so it runs this even though the output is already there.

How would i specify the makefile so that it reads in the `target`(`test_output`) but actually depends on the output file it generates like `test_output.a` or any of the other files.

Answer (score 2):

If you use GNU make (you didn't say) you can use pattern rules to tell make about a rule that generates multiple outputs based on a single stem.  So for example you can write:

```
%.a %.b %.c : test_input
        genereate.py -i $^ -o $*
```

(it would work a lot better if the input filename was related to the output filenames with the same stem, but the above will work although you'll have to write a different one for each input file).

Typically that's what you want, so that other targets that need these outputs can depend on them.

If you really want to have a target without any extension as well, just create it:

```
test_output : test_output.a test_output.b test_output.c

%.a %.b %.c : test_input
        genereate.py -i $^ -o $*
```

Comment: Sorry, i got distracted. What if the number and type of syntax in output file from generate.py varies everytime, meaning there could be `test_output.z` as well.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "every time".  Every time you run `make`?  For different `test_input` files?

Comment: @MadScientist.Sorry for confusing statement. I meant every time i run `generate.py` it generates different number of files (based on input file size) with same name but different extensions.

Comment: I still don't understand.  If you can't write down the list of files that will be generated from the input file, then make can't know what they are.  You'll have to just use a generic target, as in your first example.  If you want to avoid having it rebuild every time, just have your rule use `touch $@` or similar to create the `test_output` file so make won't rerun it next time.

Comment: yeah thats what i have it setup right now. It works fine, but i thought there would be another solution as well which might be more makefile like, if there is anything like that. thank you.

Comment: make gets all its knowledge of which files can be created and how from the makefile.  If you can't describe it in the makefile (for example if it can't be determined without running the program), then make can't know what it is.